# Complex Thread Control

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have 3 threads of execution, below describes what each thread will do.

Thread 1 - main thread
Thread 2 - detector thread
Thread 3 - action thread

When thread 1 starts, it spawns thread 2. Thread 2 will simply run alongside thread 1 and search for an event. When the event happens, I want thread 2 to spawn a new thread, thread 3. I want thread 3 to join with thread 1. Is this possible?

Sample Code:

```
 public class ThreadA {

// variable to flag if ThreadB should still loop
private static boolean runThreadB = true;

public void mainMethod() {

    new ThreadB().start();

    // do some stuff

    // make sure thread B can end
    runThreadB = false;

}

// inner class / Thread B
class ThreadB extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // loop until Thread A is done
        while (runThreadB) {

            // wait for event, if event is found, spawn thread C
            ThreadC threadC = new ThreadC();
            threadC.start();

            /**
             * Need thread C to somehow join ThreadA
             */
            try {
                threadC.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

```
 public class ThreadC extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {

    // perform some tasks

}
```

}

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  But a lot of things are possible, including nonsense stuff, and stuff that provides no utility.  You might get more mileage out of asking a more specific question, like "is this a good idea", or here's my code, why doesn't it work?

Comment: What do you mean by "*join with thread 1*"?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler if Thread 1 will spawn both threads and then wait for one or both to finish?

Comment: Who will generate the event Thread2 is supposed to catch? What is Thread 3 supposed to do?

Comment: why did I get a negative mark for this?

Comment: Added some sample code to help show what I am trying to do

Comment: what does Thread1 do after it spawned Thread2? Waits for the result of Thread3? Then connect Thread1 and Thread3 with a blocking queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must synchronize the threads. You can use `ReentrantLock` to do this.

Here is a simple example for your problem (Event producer-consumer):

```
public class Foo{
    //...

    public void consumeEvent() throws InterruptedException{
        aLock.lock();
        try {
            while(noEvent){
                eventAvailable.await();
            }
            // use the event
        } finally {
            sLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void createEvent() throws InterruptedException{
        aLock.lock();
        try {
            // add an event
            eventAvailable.signalAll();
        } finally {
            sLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private Lock aLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition eventAvailable = aLock.newCondition();
}
```

Your threads will use an object from this class.

```
Thread eventProducer = ...
Thread eventConsumer = ...
eventProducer.start();
eventConsumer.start();
```

Your threads synchronized now.

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit above? Please help in showing how I can use Re-entrant lock for this?